# How do I colour lines separately in rarecurve (vegan package)

Tags: r, vegan

I'm using `rarecurve` (`vegan`) to produce rarefaction curves for nine samples, but I want them to be coloured in groups of three.

The parameters for `rarecurve` are:

```
rarecurve(x, step = 1, sample, xlab = "Sample Size", ylab = "Species", label = TRUE, ...)
```

With the `...` passing arguments to 'plot'. However, when I replace the ellipsis with `col=c(rep("blue",3), rep("red",3), rep("darkgreen",3))`, all lines appear as blue. How do I colour the lines individually?

It takes almost three hours to compute each graph, so trial and error testing is a bit laborious!

Comment: By way of an FYI: I added this as a feature to **vegan** in [revision 2867](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=vegan&revision=2867) via similar changes to that shown in the Answer by @rawr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
## example from ?vegan::rarecurve
library(vegan)
data(BCI)
S <- specnumber(BCI)
(raremax <- min(rowSums(BCI)))
Srare <- rarefy(BCI, raremax)
plot(S, Srare, xlab = "Observed No. of Species", ylab = "Rarefied No. of Species")
abline(0, 1)
rarecurve(BCI, step = 20, sample = raremax, col = "blue", cex = 0.6)
```

[image]

```
# using new function
plot(S, Srare, xlab = "Observed No. of Species", ylab = "Rarefied No. of Species")
abline(0, 1)
rarec(BCI, step = 20, sample = raremax, cex = 0.6)
```

[image]

The problem is in these lines in `vegan::rarecurve`

```
for (ln in seq_len(length(out))) {
  N <- attr(out[[ln]], "Subsample")
  lines(N, out[[ln]], ...)
```

where each line is made individually by `lines` which in turn is only taking the first color it sees in the color argument passed by `...`, which is blue in your case. After applying a simple hack to this loop:

```
for (ln in seq_len(length(out))) {
  N <- attr(out[[ln]], "Subsample")
  lines(N, out[[ln]], col = cols[ln], ...)
```

and specifying a new argument, `cols`, in the `rarecurve` function rather than passing `col` onto `plot` and `lines`:

`cols = c(rep('red', nrow(x) / 2), rep('blue', nrow(x) / 2))`

Here is the new function

```
rarec <- function (x, step = 1, sample, xlab = "Sample Size", ylab = "Species", 
          label = TRUE, cols = c(rep('red', nrow(x) / 2), rep('blue', nrow(x) / 2)), ...) {
  tot <- rowSums(x)
  S <- specnumber(x)
  nr <- nrow(x)
  out <- lapply(seq_len(nr), function(i) {
    n <- seq(1, tot[i], by = step)
    if (n[length(n)] != tot[i]) 
      n <- c(n, tot[i])
    drop(rarefy(x[i, ], n))
  })
  Nmax <- sapply(out, function(x) max(attr(x, "Subsample")))
  Smax <- sapply(out, max)
  plot(c(1, max(Nmax)), c(1, max(Smax)), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
       type = "n", ...)
  if (!missing(sample)) {
    abline(v = sample)
    rare <- sapply(out, function(z) approx(x = attr(z, "Subsample"), 
                                           y = z, xout = sample, rule = 1)$y)
    abline(h = rare, lwd = 0.5)
  }
  for (ln in seq_len(length(out))) {
    N <- attr(out[[ln]], "Subsample")
    lines(N, out[[ln]], col = cols[ln], ...)
  }
  if (label) {
    ordilabel(cbind(tot, S), labels = rownames(x), ...)
  }
  invisible(out)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can probably get this added to the vegan development version if the other vegan developers are happy with this.